# How to move up multiple folder

Tags: cmd, command-line

Using VS Code terminal, a certain directory keeps popping up as default :
C:\Users\user\name\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4

How do move back up with one single command instead of doing multiple "cd ../.."

Much appreciated!

Comment: Move back up where? What about `cd /D "%UserProfile%"` or `cd /D "%UserProfile%\folder1"`, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I am answering for CMD as it was tagged CMD, I'm not sure how this affects VSCode.  So, I'm not sure if I should just delete this or if it is actually relevant.  Please let me know.

What folder do you want to go to?

Using your Example `C:\Users\user\name\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4`

If you would like to go to the root `CD \` will do.

If you would like to go up 4 directories `CD ..\..\..\..` will do

If you want to go up 4 directories and back down 3 `CD ..\..\..\..\folder1\folder2\folder3`

If you want to always go to a specific directory on the current disk `CD \Path\to\directory`

If you want to always go to a specific folder on another disk `CD /D DriveLetter:\Path\To\Folder` (eg `CD /D  X:\Path\To\Folder`)

Answer (score 0):

In VScode, add the exact folder in Workspace, you want to open terminal from.